# How to disable shortcodes in pages/posts with a certain string in the URL?

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I need to disable shortcodes on every page or post which url contains `/?task=delete&postid=`

Example url:
blog url/some random symbols/`?task=delete&postid=`some random symbols

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can place and try this snippet in your theme's functions.php file

**Case 1**

```
function remove_shortcode_exec_on_query(){

    // condition(s) if you need to decide not to disabling shortcode(s)
    if( empty( $_GET["task"] ) || empty( $_GET["postid"] ) || "delete" !== $_GET["task"] )

        return;

    // Condition(s) at top are not met, we can remove the shortcode(s)
    remove_all_shortcodes();    
}

add_action('wp','remove_shortcode_exec_on_query');
```

## Update

**Case 2**

if you want to remove only some specific shortcodes instead of removing all (which is not a good idea if you are using any shortcode based/visual composer based theme), you can use `remove_shortcode()` function instead of `remove_all_shortcodes()`

example code

```
function remove_shortcode_exec_on_query(){

    // condition(s) if you need to decide not to disabling shortcode(s)
    if( empty( $_GET["task"] ) || empty( $_GET["postid"] ) || "delete" !== $_GET["task"] )

        return;

    // Condition(s) at top are not met, we can remove the shortcode(s)
    remove_shortcode('NOT_NEEDED_SHORTCODE_STRING_1');
    remove_shortcode('NOT_NEEDED_SHORTCODE_STRING_2');    
}

add_action('wp','remove_shortcode_exec_on_query');
```

> Replace NOT_NEEDED_SHORTCODE_STRING with the shortcode string you want to remove

**Case 3**

If you need to disable some shortcodes from some specific part of the page, as example from page/post content, you will need to use filters for that specific part.

Example 1 ( removing ***all*** shortcodes from content )

```
function remove_shortcode_exec_on_query( $content ) {

    // condition(s) if you need to decide not to disabling shortcode(s)
    if( empty( $_GET["task"] ) || empty( $_GET["postid"] ) || "delete" !== $_GET["task"] ) 

        return $content;

   // Condition(s) at top are not met, we can remove the shortcode(s)
   return strip_shortcodes( $content );
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'remove_shortcode_exec_on_query' );
```

Example 2 (Removing ***some specific*** shortcodes from content)

```
function remove_shortcode_exec_on_query( $content ) {

    // condition(s) if you need to decide not to disabling shortcode(s)
    if( empty( $_GET["task"] ) || empty( $_GET["postid"] ) || "delete" !== $_GET["task"] ) 

        return $content;

   // Condition(s) at top are not met, we can remove the shortcode(s)
   remove_shortcode('NOT_NEEDED_SHORTCODE_STRING_1');
   remove_shortcode('NOT_NEEDED_SHORTCODE_STRING_2');

   return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'remove_shortcode_exec_on_query' );
```

> Replace NOT_NEEDED_SHORTCODE_STRING with the shortcode string you want to remove
>
> This example is about removing shortcode from "content" part of the page/post. if you want to apply it to some other part, the hook tag 'the_content' at `add_filter( 'the_content', 'remove_shortcode_exec_on_query' );` will need to replaced by relevant filter hook tag. e.g. for title, it will be `'the_title'`

Comment: It almost did the trick :) But your code is also disabled shortcode wich displays the page itself (it`s a plugin), so I only see now shortcode as page content. I think we need to add condition to remove shortcodes only from post/page content section, not the whole page.

Comment: I see, I misunderstood, so, if you need only to disable shortcode for the content part, you can use this filter hook,

`function remove_shortcode_exec_on_query( $content ){

    if( empty( $_GET["task"] ) || empty( $_GET["postid"] ) || "delete" !== $_GET["task"] )

        return $content;

    remove_all_shortcodes();
     
    return $content;    
}

add_filter('the_content','remove_shortcode_exec_on_query',10,1);`

Comment: That one broke down my site

Comment: I assume you are using some shortcode based theme(visual composer baked), if that is the case, then it's not good idea to disable shortcodes in generic way.Rather you can make a list of shortcodes which you want to disable and only disable those instead of all. (which you asked initially).
I am not sure if that is the case about the theme, but if it is, then let me know. also, [this reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_shortcode/) will help how to deactivate individual shortcode. you can use remove_shortcode function instead of remove_all_shortcode

Comment: I have updated my answer for different cases, check which case suites for your problem @Ted

Comment: Just WOW! Thank you so much!! You are a lifesaver!!